# Linq to get data from a table but not if in another table?

Tags: c#, linq

Because of a poor design on our database I have to write a complex query to get my data.

I need to get all valid data from a table_1. In other works I need to get each valid row of my table_1. I don't have a simple valid or invalid column in my table_1. This information is stored in a table_2. Table_2 contains all invalid row with the error message.

Let say the data I need to retrieve are orders. For my example notice that OrderNo is the number of an order. So I can have multiple line, version, of this order in table_1 and I can also have multiple line of error on this order in table_2. So I will also have to use a version number.

I already tried this:

```
table_1.Where(y => (y.OrderNo == "1234"));
table_2.Where(y => (y.OrderNo == "1234")).Select(y => y.Version).Distinct();
```

And I think I need to do something like this:

```
var errorList = table_2.Where(y => (y.OrderNo == "1234")).Select(y => y.Version).Distinct();
table_1.Where(y => (y.OrderNo == "1234" && y.Version.NOT_IN(erriList)));
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Sounds normal, not bad design

Comment: Do you have any foreign key between table1 and table2?

Comment: You can do it with a join.  A left outer join does a join and include where an items not in A an is in B. See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: What is the point of voting -1 without commenting it? My explanation is correct, I give examples, there is no duplicate and I tell what I already tried.

Comment: @jdweng - that works if they want all the ones with errors.  But the OP wanted to get "all valid data".

Comment: I didn't down vote it but this there has to be so many questions on SO that are either the same or very close to this one

Comment: Similar, very close yes... but not duplicate and if you find a duplicate feel free to link it then... do not just vote -1. This is not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are searching for `Contains` function with `!` symbol ([logical negation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx)). Like this:

```
var errorList = table_2.Where(y => y.OrderNo == "1234")
                       .Select(y => y.Version);

var res = table_1.Where(y => y.OrderNo == "1234" 
            //here you get only rows that doesn't represent in errorList 
            && !errorList.Contains(y.Version));
```

Comment: You don't need the Distinct(), I think the query will be faster without it.

Comment: @Mick agree, but Distinct() was in OP example. So maby there is something that we don't know

Comment: No, you probably have right. I don't need the distinct.

Comment: Why so many -1. I like this solution. Could you explain your -1?

Comment: i don't understand it either =)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer as long as the type of errorList is IQueryable<{versiontype}>

Comment: @Mick you mean i missing ToList() to be sure? I suspect Version is string type

Comment: Version is string type, yes.

Comment: I was saying you would want errorlist to be an IQueryable object... if versionType is string, then IQueryable<string>, so yes you do not want ToList().

Comment: @Mick ok, nice to know

Answer (score 1):

> to get data from a table but not if in another table

This is called [antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29). While you can use `Contains` and `Any` based approaches presented in the other answers, usually you'll get the best performance by using the classic SQL approach - `LEFT OUTER JOIN` combined with checking the right side for `NULL`.

Which in LINQ looks like this:

```
var query =
    from t1 in table_1
    //where t1.OrderNo == "1234"
    join t2 in table_2 on t1.OrderNo equals t2.OrderNo into t2group
    from t2 in t2group.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t2 == null
    select t1;
```

Actually when you use `OrderNo` filter, most probably there will not be a noticeable speed difference between this and other queries. The main benefit of the above would be if you remove that filter, although many nowadays SQL query optimizers are able to derive one and the same execution plan regardless of whether the query uses `JOIN` / `IN` / `EXISTS` constructs.

Comment: I think out of the 3 answers this will be the most efficient, in my experience joins are faster than sub queries

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var validRows = table1
                .Where(t1 => !table2
                              .Any(t2 => t1.OrderNo == t2.OrderNo && 
                                         t1.Version == t2.Version));
```

Note that this is far more efficient in SQL unless you're using something fancy that translates the expression to SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient in SQL? All linq queries will be translated to SQL, right?

Comment: @B413 - generally, so long as the data source is connected to the database, it will be.  But we don't really know table1.GetType() here without more source code.  All we know is that it's IEnumerable<T>.